# How to get snapshot of current values in employee table for attendance table?

Tags: database-design

Let say I have 2 Tables: Employees and Attendances

Employees( id, name, position, birthday, startDate, ... )

Attendances( id, clockInTime, employee_id )

In Attendances Table, I would like to store daily clock-in time of each employee.

But if in the future, for data analytic reasons, I need to get the position of employee at the time they clock-in.

So, if John is junior 5 years ago and now he a CEO, then when I query the clock-in data 5 years ago I would like to see John as Junior Position not CEO.

My question is that "Is it wise to add another column called currentPosition into Attendencs table for this purpose?" or Is there any better solution for this if there is more than 1 column in employee detail I need to save in Attendances.